# use function name as a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, discord.py

I have this function here that uses the folder name as a command. Right now the only folders are "hug" and "headpat". So when I send `.hug` or `.headpat` to Discord it will go into that folder, grab a random image and post it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        async def random_image(dir): #picks a random image from local directory
                if message.content.lower() ==f".{dir}":
                   image = random.choice(os.listdir(dir))
            
                   embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9e00)
                   chosen_one = discord.File(f"{dir}\\{image}", filename = image)

                   embed.set_image(url = f"attachment://{image}")
                   await message.channel.send (embed = embed, file = chosen_one)
                   print(f"{image} sent in response to {(message.author)}.")
                   print(f"----------")
```

However, I would like to be able to do something like as follows, but I am not sure where to start.

```
@bot.command()
async def folder_name(ctx): 
        #code that does the same as the function above
```

Comment: Can you explain it better-more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default with the [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands) extension, the function's name is the command name. However, the [`@commands.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.command) decorator have a [`aliases`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command.aliases) argument that you can use along with [`Context.invoked_with`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with):

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['hug', 'headpat'])
async def folder_name(ctx):
    image = random.choice(os.listdir(ctx.invoked_with))
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9e00)
    chosen_one = discord.File(f"{dir}\\{image}", filename=image)

    embed.set_image(url = f"attachment://{image}")
    await ctx.send (embed = embed, file=chosen_one)

    print(f"{image} sent in response to {ctx.author}.")
    print(f"----------")
```

Note that if someone types `!folder_name`, the command will execute so you'll have to add a check like this:

```py
if ctx.invoked_with == ctx.command.name:
    #Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple bot that implements your code as a command.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "your token"
PREFIXES = ['.']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIXES)


@bot.command(name='image')
async def random_image(ctx, dir):
    image = random.choice(os.listdir(dir))
            
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9e00)
    chosen_one = discord.File(f"{dir}\\{image}", filename = image)

    embed.set_image(url = f"attachment://{image}")
    await ctx.send (embed = embed, file = chosen_one)
    print(f"{image} sent in response to {(message.author)}.")
    print(f"----------")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name} in {len(bot.guilds)} guilds!")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot: # I always do this to make sure it isn't a bot
       return
    await bot.process_commands(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        bot.run(TOKEN)
    finally:
        print("Logging Out")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually recommend using **links** instead of files/folders for their **unreliable** and often **produce problems** and bugs in your code and they just don't work very well with discord.py.
Here's an **example** of your desired command.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed
import random
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

headpat_image_links = ['https://media.tenor.com/images/ad8357e58d35c1d63b570ab7e587f212/tenor.gif', 'https://image.myanimelist.net/ui/xUjg9eFRCjwANWb4t4P8QbyfbVhnxa2QGYxoE7Brq1sHDVak6YxhLP3ZbNkkHm6GX9x8FWB1tWCapNyEqSltXa8wxAdwIERdrHGhYPilHJ8']
secret_headpat = random.choice(headpat_image_links)

@client.command()
async def headpat(ctx):
    e=Embed(title="Headpats!", description="whatever description you want")
    e.set_image(url=secret_headpat)
    await ctx.send(embed=e, content=None)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

I've checked it and it **works** like a charm ;)
It's the same concept for the hug command. Just choose a **random** link to embed :)

**PS**:
Make sure you don't use any imgur links, imgur's API and links has been on the fritz and no longer works with discord.py. Well, it no longer works with embedded messages. Just don't use it. :>